# Compute the integral >$\int (x-y) dx +xy dy$ over the circle of radius 2 and centre at origin.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral
>
> $\int  (x-y) dx +xy dy$ over the circle of radius 2 and centre at origin.

**My try**:

Put $x=2\cos \theta,y=2\sin \theta $

$\int  (x-y) dx +xy dy$ becomes

$-4\int (\cos \theta -\sin \theta) \sin \theta d\theta+\int 8\sin \theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta$

$=2 \int 1-\cos 2\theta d\theta$

$=4\pi$

Is my answer correct?

Please help.

Comment: Use Green's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems good. You could have also applied Green's theorem:
\begin{align}
\oint_{x^2+y^2 = 4} (x-y)\, \mathrm dx + xy \, \mathrm dy &= \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xy) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x-y) \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4} y+1 \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4} 1 \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy = 4\pi,
\end{align}
since 
$$ \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 4} y \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy = 0 $$
by symmetry.